# Query in Controller VS in Razor View - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let say that i have a `Books` table and a `Chapters`. Those 2 tables are related in `one-to-many` relationship. And I want to make a website with ASP.NET MVC5 to display the Book Name and its Chapters. So, I can perform atleast 2 query scenarios to display needed data:

---

1. Query all data in a Controller 
BookViewModel.cs

```
class BookViewModel{
    List<Books> books{set;get;}
    List<ChapterList> chapterLists{set;get;}
}
```

ChapterList.cs

```
class ChapterList{
    List<Chapters> chapters{set;get;}
}
```

Book.cs (the Controller)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Books> books = db.Books.ToList()
    List<ChapterList> chapterList = new List<ChapterList>();
    foreach(Books m in books)
    {
        chapterLists.Add(db.Chapters.Where(m => m.book_id = m.id).ToList());
    }
    BookViewModel bvm = new BookViewModel();
    bvm.books = books;
    bvm.chapterLists = chapterLists
    return view();
}
```

Index.cshtml (the View) --I think I'll skip this code, because I assume you know how to display it

---

2. Query in Razor 
  Book.cs (the Controller)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Books> books = db.Books.ToList()
    return view(books);
}
```

Index.cshtml (the View)

```
@foreach(Books book in model)
{
    @book.Name
    foreach(Chapters chapter in book.Chapters.ToList())
    {
        @chapter.Name
    }
}
```

The second query scenario is the easiest for me, but I am not sure which one is faster. So, my question is which one is the best performance (or the fastest displaying the view) if there are million `Books` data and the databases is in a different server? And is there any other way to display the view faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) method on DbSet.

I tried to simpler and faster your query. You can check below.
In controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new YourDbContext();
        var booksWithChapterList =
            db.Books
            .Include(s => s.chapterLists) //I add chapterList to query, so I don't fetch another query.
            .Select(s => new BookDto// I convert them to smaller data transfer object.
            {
                Name = s.Name,
                Chapters = s.chapterLists.Select(w => new BookChapterDto
                {
                    Name = w.Name
                }).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
        return View(booksWithChapterList);
    }
}
```

You can find used classes here:

```
public class BookDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<BookChapterDto> Chapters { get; set; }

}
public class BookChapterDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other faster way to display data in entity Framework, one of them is by  using LINQ Queries.

In Your Controller you could do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Books> books = db.Books.ToList()
    List<ChapterList> chapterList = (from a in db.Books
                                    join b in db.Charpters on a.id equals b.BookId
                                    //where a.id==3 you can also query for specific book
                                    select new ChapterList
                                    {
                                     chapter=b.chapter
                                    }).ToList();

    BookViewModel bvm = new BookViewModel();
    bvm.books = books;
    bvm.chapterLists = chapterLists
    return view();
}
```

This will be faster than looping through each item using foreach.

It is always a good practice to keep all your logic in controller level instead of view.